# When we close a question, can we have an option to send it to Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, migration, closed-questions

Since Stack Overflow can send it here, I figure it's only fair to have the ability to send them the other way.  There's been a number of questions that are Stack Overflow type questions..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally beta sites don't have close migration paths to anywhere but their meta. I've personally migrated a fair number of questions to both SO and Programmers, and as the site grows I anticipate more. I think that the number of migrations can be evaluated after launch and the path added if necessary (the team can clarify this further).

However, moderators can migrate to any site. If you come across a question that you feel belongs on another site in the network, please flag it and we will migrate as necessary. I won't migrate a question if it's a bad question (like [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3576/file-move-which-is-in-process-closed)), but if it's decent I will edit/migrate. Otherwise the question will be closed as off-topic.

The same goes for any other problem posts - we moderators are here for when the community can't take action. I look at as many posts as I can, but we can't keep up with everything. Feel free to flag whenever you feel something's wrong. (Plus, you can get a shiny <strike>gold star</strike> [Deputy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/badges/65/deputy) badge!)

Comment: cool, I'll just flag them when I see them.

Comment: Note that it's the same way the other way around: SO questions can only be migrated to codereview by moderators as well.